# Unity Random Color

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

I'm trying to generate a random color for a glass material using a script, but it doesn't work in the right way.

This is the material:
[image: This is the Material]

So, the script is the following:

```
Color c = new Color(Random.Range(0f,1f), Random.Range(0f,1f), Random.Range(0f,1f));
c.a = 30; 
....
....
GameObject.Find("Plane").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = c; //Repeat this line for each glass wall.
```

And when the color changes, the result is the following:

This is the initial color:
[image: This is the initial color]

And this is the generated color: [image: This is the generated color]

What is wrong?

Comment: You have the alpha set to 30, but the range is 0-1.  Probably not the main issue, but something I noticed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to generate random color:

```
UnityEngine.Random.ColorHSV()
```

Comment: I tried to use it, but the result is the same.

Comment: What do you expect? You want good color like yellow ?